# HTML5 datalist tag is not populating in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, html, safari

I have a datalist tag which allows my users to have a suggestion box. However, I've noticed that this feature is not supported in safari. Is there a workaround to this issue?

Here is my code - I'm actually populating my values with an ajax method but this is what it would look like after it's populated:

```
<datalist id="languages">
    <option value="HTML">
    <option value="CSS">
    <option value="JavaScript">
    <option value="Java">
    <option value="Ruby">
    <option value="PHP">
    <option value="Go">
    <option value="Erlang">
    <option value="Python">
    <option value="C">
    <option value="C#">
    <option value="C++">
</datalist>

Search: 
<input type="text" list="languages">
```

I also have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ag92668/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Datalist elements are not supported in Safari.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist

Comment: is there a workaround for this? I've only found a way to convert the datalist into a dropdown list. but that's not what I want. thanks

Comment: Not easily.  One hack: you can create a select box with an "Other" option at the top or bottom.  When "Other" is selected, you could reveal a text box for the user to type in something not in the list.

Comment: What about some kind of css and javascript that would emulate an autocomplete in safari?

Comment: https://github.com/thgreasi/datalist-polyfill  may help do this. It looks like the code supports browsers that do not support datalists.

Comment: yep, I just saw that before you posted. That should work very nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

## HTML5 datalist workaround for Safari and/or older browsers

### Update, Jun 2022

Safari (untested by me) now supports the `datalist` tag—[see this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541258/123033). However, [Firefox has some issues, as outlined on *caniuse*](https://caniuse.com/datalist).

### Update, Jan 2017

Both iOS or desktop [Safari still do not support datalist](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist), and there's no sign so far of this changing. So this is a hack making it *appear* to get around the issue. Chris Coyier also had a go at a [datalist polyfill back in 2011](https://css-tricks.com/relevant-dropdowns-polyfill-for-datalist/). Let's hope Safari implements the [existing W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element) in future.

### Original post:

You can [use a `select` element](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/08/html-5-datalist-element-with-fallback.html) inside the `datalist`, and duplicate the `option` tag values as readable text in these. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
    input[list="languages"] {
      width: 12em;
      border: none;
      background: #eee;
    }
    select {
      width: 12em;
      margin: 0;
      margin-left: -12.75em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

Choose: <input type="text" list="languages">
<label for="languages">
  <datalist id="languages">
    <select>
      <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
      <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
      <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
      <option value="Go">Go</option>
      <option value="Python">Python</option>
      <option value="etc">etc</option>
    </select>
  </datalist>
</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Supporting browsers will just display the `datalist`, Safari and older browsers will show the `option` tags' innerHTML. The `input` tag has a default border, which in Safari looks bad behind the `select` element, but with a little styling as shown in this example, you can get around Safari's lack of support and keep the same functional appearance. No need for Javascript and/or polyfills.

Comment: To clarify, Safari will show a select element in front of the input. It will not have the same behavior as a datalist where you can either enter arbitrary input or choose from a list of suggestions.

Comment: unfortunately with this solution on safari or other browser that don't support **<datalist>** to users is completely precluded the possibility to type other values because the **<select>** element allows to select the content only but doesn't allow typing. So a part of the behavior is dead in a not replaceable way for all such users... In fact for them the example works like the **<input type="text" list="languages">** wasn't even present

Comment: IMHO the best way to go (for future HTML 6?) would be to have just the **<select>** tag with a new attribute something like **editable="true"** to allow editing and a new attribute like **filterable="true"** to allow filtering while typing. While the **<datalist>** tag would be useful to share options between more than one select. But all this is another story, just a hope for future development of the w3c html 6 standards... The **<select>** tag is in fact the "logical/consistent/natural" tag to have a selectable list of options in it. the **<input type="text">** is not the right way to go.

Comment: i run into the same issues. I believed that [Apples HTML Ref: datalist](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/HTMLTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001262-SW13) is supported by their Browsers.... or it is new there since some changes in 2017.

Comment: Joe, I see the reference in the docs but can't seem to get it working in Safari 10.1.  Has anyone gotten it to work?  Here's my example:   <html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <input name="state" list="states">
    <datalist id="states">
     <option>Alabama</option>
     <option>Alaska</option>
     <option>Wyoming</option>
    </datalist>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>

Answer (score 10):

As of Safari 12.1, datalist is now finally supported. Please see the [Apple release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_12_1_release_notes#3130314).

It seems that the developer of the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) [recommended polyfill](https://github.com/mfranzke/datalist-polyfill) stays quite up to date:

> Update: Safari TP supports the datalist element at least basically, and its functionality will be included within the next release of Safari both for iOS and MacOS X. Yeah !!! Exciting news! I'm planning to release a new major version soon to both cheer as well as accommodate their implementation

Answer (score 8):

I realize its a bit late, but, for those who want a solution that mimics datalist on Safari, rather than replacing it with a select:

https://github.com/Fyrd/purejs-datalist-polyfill

Basically a short and sweet .js and .css that you can include in your html and it makes datalists linked inputs behave the same on Safari and Opera mini as they do on Chrome, Firefox and Android Browser.

Comment: We went for this one to support datalist on safari. Thank you for your recommendation.

Comment: It works perfect. I made some mods for aesthetic reasons. Check it in [link](https://github.com/Fyrd/purejs-datalist-polyfill/issues)

Comment: I am having issues with safari... Works great on iOS chrome

Comment: not working in iOS Safari for me. (iPhone X 11.2) And weird behavior in Mac OS High Sierra Safari: the autocomplete datalist appears once you start typing but only in the top left hand corner of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

First, thank you George for you script that work again today. For those which get trouble cause your options are display in the top left hand corner (like iamse7en) you should modify these lines in datalist.polyfill.js :

56 :

`document.body.appendChild( fakeList );
 document.getElementById("myIdDiv").appendChild( fakeList );`

Bescause in the exemple on the github project it was only one div in the body so it was not a problem.

110 :

`input.value = item.innerText;
 input.value = item.innerHTML;`

To click anywhere on the item and not only on the text.

And finaly add the `<script src="/static/js/datalist.polyfill.js"></script>` on your html file but not the version datalist.polyfill.min.js

Comment: Thanks for the polyfill tip, works great ! created codepen if someone wants to check: https://codepen.io/arlevi/pen/gEqvRb

Answer (score 0):

Further to what Mianto said regarding iamse7en's issue, in order to bind your datalist to a dynamic DIV (the example Mianto gave and then Moritz edited is hard-coded), change the following at line 51:

```
function convert(input, datalist, listItems) {
    var fakeList = document.createElement('ul');
    var visibleItems = null;
    fakeList.id = listId;
    fakeList.className = LIST_CLASS;
    document.body.appendChild( fakeList );
```

to:

```
function convert(input, datalist, listItems) {
    var fakeList = document.createElement('ul');
    var visibleItems = null;
    fakeList.id = listId;
    fakeList.className = LIST_CLASS;
    input.parentNode.style.position = "relative";
    input.parentNode.appendChild( fakeList );
```