# Datalist attribute is not working in google chrome

Tags: html, attributes

Datalist attribute is not working in Google chrome, it is working fine in Firefox

Please have a look here http://prntscr.com/arny81

Thanks for your help in advance.

HTML

```
<td><input onkeyup="showCustomers(this.value)" placeholder="Enter Customer Name" list="selectCust" name="Cno" />
<datalist id="selectCust">
                    </datalist>
</td>
```

Javascript

```
function showCustomers(str) {
     if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("selectCust").innerHTML = "";
    return;
    } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("selectCust").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getCustomers.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

getCustomers.php File

```
<?php include('conn.php'); ?>
<?php // get the q parameter from URL

$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
if ($q !== "") {
$q = strtolower($q);
$len=strlen($q);


                    $sql2 = 'SELECT Customer_Name as Cname,No from customers order by Customer_Name';
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) { 
                        ?><option value=""></option><?php
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) { 
                        if (stristr($q, substr($row2["Cname"], 0, $len))) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php 
                                echo $row2['No']; ?>"><?php echo $row2["Cname"]; ?></option>
                    <?php } }  ?>
                <?php } } ?>
```

I have not used CSS at all.

Answer (score 0):

Target the ID in your CSS instead, that should work fine.

HTML:

```
<datalist id="dl">
   Your content goes here
</datalist>
```

CSS:

```
#dl {
   display: block;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome or any other browser.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to target ID in CSS?

Comment: Actually i have not written datalist{ display:none}, this is automatically done by browser

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS so I can see what is wrong there.

Comment: Hello Goncalopinto, Please Check my Edited Question.

Comment: Did you try to add the CSS I included in my answer? It worked well for me in several projects, I tried yesterday again (just to confirm it works fine in the new Chrome), i tried in Firefox, IE, and Edge and all worked fine. But you need to set in in CSS otherwise it won't work (in Chrome at least).

Comment: Try this for testing, it will work for sure:
 <datalist id="selectCust" style="display: block">
      testing
 </datalist>

Comment: This is same http://prntscr.com/as2s5c, It is looking weird and I cannot select anyone of them

Comment: Is there any other alternative for datalist, Like by merging Select Dropdown and Input Textfield.

Comment: Check this article, I think it has all the info you need to resolve your issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494084/html5-datalist-tag-is-not-populating-in-safari
Check this one too:
http://www.devcurry.com/2011/08/html-5-datalist-element-with-fallback.html

Comment: It is also not solving,any other option instead of datalist?

Comment: You have a workaround and full documentation about datalists here: http://www.noupe.com/design/html5-datalists-what-you-need-to-know-78024.html