# Datalist shows far from input

Tags: html, css, html-datalist

I am executing a simple auto-complete with datalist and input.
The problem is that the datalist shows far from input area.
I am using Tailwind with React for this project.

```
<div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Search for products, brands"
        className="w-full p-4 text-sm rounded-lg bg-transparent border-solid border-2 border-black bg-white"
        onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
        list="categories"
      />
      <datalist id="categories">
        {categories.map((category) => (
          <option value={category.name} />
        ))}
      </datalist>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: do you have any CSS/stylesheets? If so, can we see the styles for the datalist and input?

Comment: No stylesheet, I only use Tailwind.

Comment: hmm... this has never happened to me before. I'm of course not that smart, and cannot think of a reason why it's happening. If this persists, you can get desperate and program your own autocomplete.

Comment: Where can we see this running? Have a link?

Comment: The problem was from Chrome, I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593924/datalist-attribute-is-not-working-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Update, I found it a bug in Chrome after checking in Firefox.

Here is a fix to the problem
[fixing datalist problem with Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593924/datalist-attribute-is-not-working-in-google-chrome)