# Datalist is not showen on iphone

Tags: html, iphone

i am designing a simple form using HTML using an input , that input has a data list , the data list's options are working fine on desktop browsers (Chrome,Firefox),but when i access the page from an iphone Device using (Safari,Firefox,Chrome) the data list couldn't appear, is there an alternative tags is used for those browsers instead of `<datalist>` ?
here is an example for my simple code

```
<input type="text" name="x" list="list"/>
<datalist id="list">
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
</datalist>
```

any ideas to show those options ?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, just want to point out that support for datalist is not well on mobile: http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist. Best suggestion I have is a polyfill: https://github.com/thgreasi/datalist-polyfill

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 datalist tag is not populating in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494084/html5-datalist-tag-is-not-populating-in-safari)

Answer (score 1):

**DUPLICATE QUESTION** - Please refer to this question/answer for the work around for iPhone/Safari:
[HTML5 datalist tag is not populating in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494084/html5-datalist-tag-is-not-populating-in-safari)

You can scroll down and find more UTD answers as well.