# Dropdown menu using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax

I have installed a dropdown menu (in a php site) that makes use of Ajax functionality to populate the dropdown list.  It works ok, except that the list only populates if you tab into the dropdown button.  If you click on the button it needs two clicks to populate (this tends to throw people in a major way).

The function is called from a focus event.  I have tried click, onclick, load, onload and others, but nothing works.

The form code reads;

```
echo "<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.sel_field').focus(function(){


            $.ajax({
                url: 'GetClient.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){

                    var len = response.length;

                    $('#sel_user').empty();
                    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                        var id = response[i]['id'];
                        var name2 = response[i]['username'];
                        var name = response[i]['name'];
                        var mat = response[i]['Matter'];

                        $('#sel_user').append('<option value='+id+'> ClientID: '+id+' -  Name:   '+name+' : '+mat+'</option>');


                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });


</script>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "Client ID <span style='font-size:10px'>(Press tab to enter)</span>";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<select  name='clientID' style='width:460px' class='form-control sel_field' id='sel_user' >
        <option value='0'> - Make A Selection -</option>
    </select>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to help you without knowing what you're expecting and what you're actually getting. I've made a snippet based on your code, replacing the ajax call with a setTimeout function. It's doing something... how close/far is it to what you're experiencing and what exactly are you expecting?

-- EDIT: maybe the delay for the load is throwing people? I've added a line to change the select text to "loading" while waiting for the ajax to finish what it's doing.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sel_field').focus(function(){
         $('#sel_user').html('<option value="0">Loading...</option>');
         setTimeout(function(){

           var len = 2;

           $('#sel_user').empty();
           for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
               var id = 1;
               var name2 = 'name2-'+i;
               var name = 'name-'+i;
               var mat = 'mat'+i;

               $('#sel_user').append('<option value='+id+'> ClientID: '+id+' -  Name:   '+name+' : '+mat+'</option>');
           }
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
<td>
Client ID <span style='font-size:10px'>(Press tab to enter)</span>
</td>
<td>
<select  name='clientID' style='width:460px' class='form-control sel_field' id='sel_user' >
        <option value='0'> - Make A Selection -</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.  So what I want is the dropdown to populate on one click.  It is currently populating on two clicks.  You wills see that your snippet is performing in the same way.  Cheers

Comment: On my computer it's populating in one click (you have to wait a second because I set the timeout to 1000 ms to simulate a slow connection)

Comment: I've edited the code to have the text display "loading" immediately (one click) as it waits to populate

Comment: It is a Safari problem!  It all works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Gosh, very generous of you to accept my answer even though I haven't resolved your problem. Indeed, I tried the code on Safari and it doesn't work. Out of curiosity I've been looking for a work around but to no avail. Have you figured it out? One thing I've noticed - clicking out of the select element also updates it, so I suspect it's not a case of the select needing two clicks but rather the select isn't redrawn until something happens later. Maybe a clue towards a workaround?

Comment: No I haven't sorted it out for Safari.  Yes, clicking outside the element does update it.  Apparently datalist elements are not supported in Safari;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494084/html5-datalist-tag-is-not-populating-in-safari - but this is a separate issue.

Comment: I will re-post this as a Safari problem